# Elasticsearch reindexing - missing child mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, reindex

I have elastic index with join mapping, I created new index, performed reindexing. The issue is related to mapping on new index, I have all fields in new mapping except fields from document that is defined as child in join mapping. Is is expected behaviour? Why it is missing?

Comment: Before reindex try to copy the mapping from the source index and create the new index with the new mapping after that trigger the reindex. 1. `GET source_index/_mapping` 2. `PUT dest_index` 3. ` POST _reindex`

Comment: thanks for hint, but I have tried it before, and want to avoid manual mapping creation

Comment: can you share the reindex command and mappings for both source and dest indices